# setting constructor of inherited class gives error of no default constructor exists

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

I am having an issue where I am trying to initialize an "array" in my constructor, which I have done before with this method and it worked fine, however this time the class I am trying to do this this to is using inheritance (not used this a lot so could be something easy). I am getting an error saying that "No default constructor exists for class "Control_Reg_Value_HV", but I have fully defined that class with all special member functions needed.

Below shows the parts of the code I feel are important. I know that if I make a constructor then the compiler wont generate any for me, but I thought that the Control_Reg_Value_HV class is or does have default constructors.

Any help with this would be great.
Thanks in advance.

```
class Control_Reg_Value_HV;
class Data_SPI;

class Control_Reg_Value_HV{

public:

//----------------Special Member functions-----------------
Control_Reg_Value_HV(uint16_t Control_Write_Value_, uint16_t Control_Store_Value_);   //Constructor

Control_Reg_Value_HV(const Control_Reg_Value_HV& C);  //Copy Constructor

Control_Reg_Value_HV& operator=(const Control_Reg_Value_HV& C);   //Equals Function

~Control_Reg_Value_HV(){}    // Destructor

//---------------------------------------------------------

// rest of class, get and sets etc
);
//---------------------------------------------------------
//special member function definitions here

//------------------------Constructor definitions-----------------------------------------
Control_Reg_Value_HV::Control_Reg_Value_HV(uint16_t Control_Write_Value_, uint16_t Control_Store_Value_ )
                    :Control_Write_Value(Control_Write_Value_),Control_Store_Value(Control_Store_Value_){}                                       

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//class with inheritance - where the issue is

class Data_SPI:public: Control_Reg_Value_HV{

public:
//----------------Special Member functions-----------------
//static uint16_t position;


Data_SPI()
    :Resistance_Val_HV{10,11}{} //how ever many values needed, Issue here


private:
uint16_t Resistance_Val_HV[200];

    
//---------------------------------------------------------


};
```

edit:

```
no default constructor exists for class "Control_Reg_Value_HV" C/C++(291)[Ln 93, Col 30
```

sorry I dont know how to put error messages in correct format here

edit 2: missed the public: from the inherited class

edit 3: added a constructor definition

Comment: Please [edit] and show the verbatim error log and make clear which lines the line numbers in the error log refer to. Also you could make a [mcve] (requires some work), which BTW might help you to find the solution yourself.

Comment: Please write down the exact detailed list of action that in your opinion should happen when you write `Data_SPI my_data;` What initialisations are performed and in what order?

Comment: Fixing the obvious compiler error (class `Control_Reg_Value_HV` is closed with `);` when it should be `};`). the error is blatantly obvious. Your class `Data_SPI` inherits from  class `Control_Reg_Value_HV`. The constructor for `Data_SPI` makes no base-class construction call in the base/member initialization list; it simply (and oddly) initializes member `Resistance_Val_HV`. I *think* you intended to have a base/member list like `: Control_Reg_Value_HV{10, 11}`.

Comment: You forgot to tell us which lines in your code is line 93.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `Data_SPI` is also a `Control_Reg_Value_HV`, so when you try to construct a `Data_SPI` you both have to instantiate its members AND construct the underlying `Control_Reg_Value_HV`.

So either add a default constructor to `Control_Reg_Value_HV`, or explicitly add a call to the constructor with appropriate values:

```
Data_SPI()
    :Control_Reg_Value_HV{  <insert arguments here> },
     Resistance_Val_HV{10,11}{}
```

EDIT: **************

Hokay, an example:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(int x, int y)
        : _x{x}, _y{y}
    {
    }

private:
    int _x;
    int _y;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived()         // Default contructor
        : Base{0, 0}, // Call the constructor of Base with appropriate default values
          _z{0}       // Initialize the members of Derived with appropriate default values
    {
    }

    Derived(int x, int y, int z) // Explicit constructor
        : Base{x, y},            // Pass some of the arguments on to the Base constructor
          _z{z}                  // Use the rest to initialize the members of Derived
    {
    }

private:
    int _z;
};
```

Comment: Great thank you, where you have added <insert argument here>, what is suppose to go there, the default constructor?  or something else.

Comment: Well, it is a call to one of the `Control_Reg_Value_HV` constructors, so you put whatever the most appropriate one of them takes.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions but how would you go about adding the additional constructor, is this done in the Control_Reg_Value_HV class along with its definition? Because wouldn't that mean that my private member variables for DATA_SPI, will be inside the Control_Reg_Value_HV class. I have made an edit to show a definition for my constructor for the Control_Reg_Value_HV class.

Comment: I made an edit, does that answer your question?